# SQL constraint fail

Tags: sql, constraints, mariadb

So i have two tables, i do not know why adding constraint fails. I get following error:  Error creating foreign key on course_id (check data types).

Tables:

[image]

[image]

I am adding a constraint on groups table:

[image]

Course_id on groups table matches id on courses table. These two are not used in any other constraints.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean they are not used in any other constraints? Your picture shows a foreign key on course_id.

Comment: i need to add index on course_id so i could use it for constraint, dont i?

Comment: Can you provide us with the SQL definitions of both tables?

Comment: its fine now. not sure why but i deleted course_id and created a new one with the same properties.. now it works. thanks anyway.